# Apply css class to specific items in a cell in Ag-Grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am using Ag-grid in an angular 7 application. I am trying to apply a css class to specific cells using "cellClassRules". This applies the class to the entire cell. But I want to apply the class to some specific items in the cell. 
e.g. The cell contains 2 names as a single string, "ABC, XYZ, PQR". In this case I want to apply the css to only XYZ and not to the other names. This css is applied based on a specific condition. 
but this applies the class to the entire cell. Can the css be applied to only specific items in the cell?

Comment: I have tried cellClassRules: {
            "memberInactive": function(params) {
              return params.value == "ABC, XYZ, PQR";
            }
          },

Comment: Yes it can, you can use ngStyle directive. You could add it to cells and call a function in your component you return the style based on the condition. eg: [ngStyle]="setGridStyle(param)"

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be a work around though you can try and let me know,
in your example string you are passing as data try to add a `<span>` tag ,
example: `"ABC,<span class="your-class">XYZ</span>,PQR"`
then as usual you assign style to your-class.